# Failed to load anything template with laravel 5 and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, angular-ui-router

I have a problem to load some template to "/" index laravel 5 route with angularjs utilizing `$stateProvider` or `$routeProvider` or wherever.

The content of index.blade.php is fine, and every time I access directly on web browser the urls to templates everything also is fine.

The problem is load with angularjs. This error present on developer console:

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /templates/site/home (HTTP status: undefined undefined)
```

So, I customized my laravel routes utilizing `{path?}` and `Route::any()`.

I utilize `templates` as prefix but doesn't exists in fact. This is only virtual url to laravel routes to utilize.

[image]

This implementation is below:

web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application.
| These routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
*/

Route::group(['prefix' => 'panel'], function () {

    Route::any('{path?}', function () {
        return view('panel/index');
    })->where('path', '.+');

});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'templates'], function () {

    Route::any('{path?}', function ($name) {

        dd($name);

        return view($name);
    })->where('path', '.+');

});

Route::group(['prefix' => ''], function () {

    Route::any('{path?}', function () {
        return view('site/index');
    })->where('path', '.+');

});
```

app.js

```
var panelTplDir = '/templates/panel';
var siteTplDir = '/templates/site';


/***********************************
 * Routes of website without panel -
 * ---------------------------------
 *
 * @type {{name: string, url: string, templateUrl: string, controller: string}}
 */

// Routes to out panel.
var siteIndexRoute = {
    name: 'index',
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: siteTplDir + '/home',
    controller: 'IndexCtrl as index'
};
var notfoundRoute = {
    name: 'notfound',
    url: '/not_found',
    templateUrl: siteTplDir + '/notfound',
    controller: 'SiteCtrl as site',
    params: {
        route: null,
        paramSearch: null
    }
};

// Routes of authentication.
var authRoute = {
    name: 'login',
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: siteTplDir + '/auth/login',
    controller: 'AuthController as auth'
};
var registRoute = {
    name: 'register',
    url: '/register',
    templateUrl: siteTplDir + '/auth/register',
    controller: 'AuthController as auth'
};


/**********************************
 * Routes of administration panel -
 * --------------------------------
 *
 * @type {{name: string, url: string, templateUrl: string, controller: string}}
 */

// Routes of dashboard.
var homeRoute = {
    name: 'panelIndex',
    url: '/panel/dashboard',
    templateUrl: panelTplDir + '/home',
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl as home'
};

// Routes of user.
var userMeRoute = {
    name: 'me',
    url: '/panel/me',
    templateUrl: panelTplDir + '/users/user_info',
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl as user'
};
var usersRoute = {
    name: 'userList',
    url: '/panel/users',
    templateUrl: panelTplDir + '/users/get_users',
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl as user'
};

// Routes of stores.
var storeIndexRoute = {
    name: 'storeIndex',
    url: '/panel/stores',
    templateUrl: panelTplDir + '/stores/index',
    controller: 'StoresController as store'
};
```

And so...

I don't undestand what's happening with templates just out `panel` route.

[image]

.

Here, everything is fine.

[image]

.

Here, everything is fine.

[image]

.

Here, everything is fine.

[image]

### Update

Fourtunately I found the solution here [Angular ui.bootstrap failing to load templates](http://envyandroid.com/angular-ui-bootstrap-failing-to-load-templates/)

After some tests I realized that HTTP request interceptor was stoped the $templateCache from working properly.

After adding an exception to the interceptor (so that it would ignore "requests" going to the template cache) it all worked just fine.

Interceptor code:

```
request: function (config) {
config.headers = config.headers || {};

if (config.url.startsWith("/templates/")) {
    //Not modifying requests to these urls, 
    //as they are angular template cache requests
    return config;
}

//Do the interceptor work here. Add headers or whatever.
return config;
```

Comment: The `$httpProvider` interceptors caused this problem. Fourtunately I found the solution on these 2 links: https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/5yzhzu/typescript_interceptor_causes_failed_to_load/ and http://envyandroid.com/angular-ui-bootstrap-failing-to-load-templates/